# Reverse String Not functioning properly

Tags: c++

**i m trying to create a reverse string code but it doesnt output anything**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  string name = "dog";
  string reverse;
  int count = name.length();
 for (int i=0;i<count;i++){
    reverse[i]= name[count-i-1];
    cout<<i<<endl;
 }
  cout<<reverse<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the undefined behaviour. reverse.size() is 0. Use reverse.push_back(name[count-i-1]).

Comment: what does that mean sorry i m sorta starting out

Comment: Thanks reverse.push_back(name[count-i-1]) works, i didnt know i could use pushback in string and thought it was only for vectors

Comment: You could also use `reverse.resize(name.length());`.

Comment: `std::string` can take iterators for constructor. Consider declaring `string reverse(name.crbegin(), name.crend());`.

Answer (score 2):

The `string` `reverse` is 0 characters long so when you try assigning characters to it using `operator[]`, you write *out of bounds*, making your program have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

One way to solve the problem is to create it with the same length as `name`:

```
string reverse(name.size(),' ');
```

or, to instead leave it as is, and add characters to it:

```
string reverse;
reverse.reserve(name.size()); // reserve space (may make it a little faster)

for (int i=0;i<count;i++){
    reverse.emplace_back(name[count-i-1]); // or push_back
}
```

Another option could be to use `std::copy` and copy it in reverse using the `std::string`s reverse iterators:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

std::copy(name.rbegin(), name.rend(), std::back_inserter(reverse));
```

or, if you don't need to keep the original content in `name`, you could reverse it directly:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::reverse(name.begin(), name.end()); // reverses name itself
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily fix your original code by changing 1 line of code

This is the WRONG code (Original Code) :

```
reverse[i]= name[count-i-1]; // WRONG -- ORIGINAL code inside the for loop
```

This is the CORRECT code (New Code):

```
reverse += name[count-i-1]; // CORRECT code
```

Here is the full and correct code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  string name = "dog";
  string reverse;
  int count = name.length();
 for (int i=0;i<count;i++){
    reverse += name[count-i-1];  // I fixed it here. It works now.
    cout<<reverse[i]<<endl;
 }
  cout<<reverse<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

---

I have tested and verified that it works now.

Comment: Yes, this is more like it. +1  (I'd remove `#include <stdio.h>` though. It's not needed)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping with that code. I've learned something new today. :-)

Comment: OK. I've removed #include <stdio.h>  as it's not needed. Thanks to you and all others for helping me to improve this code for the OP.  Cheers. :-)

Answer (score -2):

You want to set up your forLoop backwards. Do `for( int i = ( count-1 ) ; i >= 0 ; i-- ){...}`

Edit: initialize reverse to "" and simplify the inside of the new for loop to be `reverse = ( reverse + name.at(i) ) ;` and only do the final `cout` after the loop finishes (get rid of the inside one)